# ContextBroker unexpected error

Tags: fiware-orion

We have a contextBroker version 1.0.0 and yesterday we had the below unexpected error.

```
log directory: '/var/log/contextBroker'
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'mongo::AssertionException'
    what(): assertion src/mongo/bson/bsonelement.cpp:392
log directory:'/var/log/contextBroker'
```

---

Could someone please tell us why it could have happened?

The petition that we do is the below:

```
HttpUri=http://172.21.0.33:1026/v1/updateContext 
HttpMethod=POST 
Accept=application/json 
Content-Type=application/json 
Fiware-Service=tmp_015_adapter 
Fiware-ServicePath=/Prueba/Planta_3
    {
                    "contextElements": [{
                                   "type": "device_reading",
                                   "isPattern": "false",
                                   "id": "xxxxx",
                                   "attributes": [{
                                                   "name": "timestamp",
                                                   "type": "string",
                                                   "value": "2016-06-14T12:02:03.000Z"
                                   }, {
                                                   "name": "location",
                                                   "type": "coords",
                                                   "value": "23.295132549930024, 2.1797946491494258"
                                   }, {
                                                   "name": "mac",
                                                   "type": "string",
                                                   "value": "xxxxx"
                                   }, {
                                                   "name": "densityPlans",
                                                   "type": "string",
                                                   "value": "R-B2"
                                   }, {
                                                   "name": "floor",
                                                   "type": "string",
                                                   "value": "Prueba_planta3"
                                   }, {
                                                   "name": "manufacturer",
                                                   "type": "string",
                                                   "value": "Xiaomi+Communications"
                                   }, {
                                                   "name": "rssi",
                                                   "type": "string",
                                                   "value": "9"
                                   }]
                    }],
                    "updateAction": "APPEND" }
```

The error that shows in the application because of contextBroker's error is:

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: 172.21.0.33:1026 failed to respond
```

Comment: Could you edit your question post to elaborate a little bit on the cause of the problem, please? For example, if the problem was caused by a request issued to Orion, please include the exact request in your post (verb + url + headers + payload). Thanks!

Comment: I have edited the cuestion.

Comment: I have tested Orion 1.0.0 with that request and I'm afraid I'm unable of reproducing the problem... The following link shows the details (including curl-based script to reproduce that same request): https://gist.github.com/fgalan/47deda3d34a59e7d09c1f95fcdb76032. I'd recommend you to try the same procedure and see how it goes. If it goes ok, try to find the differences between your test and mine (e.g. how CB was startes, initial DB status -mine is empty before starting the test, etc.). Please, update your question post with any relevant input or fact you find.